# Is there incremental deployment module for Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, deployment

I can find Deploy module for Drupal 7 that achieves full deployment. Also, I can find Incremental Deploy module for Drupal 6. Is there incremental deployment module for Drupal 7? or even work around that achieves incremental deployment for Drupal 7?

Comment: What the module for Drupal 6 did you find? This https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy module don't provide needed functionality for you? Wbat you mean when say "incremental deployment"?

Comment: Drupal 6&7 Deploy module is: (https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy). Drupal 6 Incremental Deploy module is: (https://www.drupal.org/project/incremental_deploy). I mean with "Incremental Deployment", continuous synchronization of content and configuration between two Drupal sites.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Drupal 7 version of Incremental Deploy. In fact, the Drupal 6 version is no longer supported.

You have several options to duplicate the functionality. The closest match is probably Data Export Import -  https://www.drupal.org/project/data_export_import

Other options are the Migrate module - https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate or migrate_d2d - https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d

Modules for migrating specific content types are also available. For example, for taxonomies, Taxonomy CSV import/export - https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv

Answer (score 0):

Deployment module for Drupal 7 can be combined with Rules to create setup similar to Incremental Deploy. See https://www.drupal.org/node/1406136 for more info about that (you'll neeed to scroll down a bit).